# How to sort a list of strings with a specific format using string.split?

Tags: c#, linq

I am receiving files that have filenames with the following format: 
**File_1242161_08112019010101PM** and **File_1710485_08112019111721AM**.
 I need to process these files in the order of the datetime in the third section of  the string. I also want to be able to handle files that don't follow this particular format, e.g.: 
 **File_666840**

I want to sort the list form earliest datetime to latest, and if there is no datetime, move to the bottom of the list sorting by the filename. I tried the following:

```
List<string> sorted = filenames.OrderByDescending(file => file.Name.Split('_').Count())
                .ThenBy(file => file.Name.Split('_').LastOrDefault().ToList());
```

This gets me almost all the way there but the AM/PM is not sorting correctly. The filename with 01:01:01 PM will show up before 11:17:21 AM for obvious reasons. What would be the most performant and most LINQ way of accomplishing what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) with the *format* `MMddyyyyhhmmsstt` and select to a [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples?view=netframework-4.8) or something.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.

<sub>*Since this is split apart now, you can order any way you like, this is just an example*</sub>

**Given**

```
var list = new List<string>()
              {
                 "File_1242161_08112019010101PM",
                 "File_1710485_08112019111721AM",
                 "File_1710488",
                 "File_1710489",
                 "File_1710480"
              };
```

**Code**

```
var orderedList = list.Select<string, (string Value, DateTime? Date)>(
                          x =>
                             {
                                var results = x.Split('_');

                                if (results.Length < 3)
                                   return (x, (DateTime?)null);

                                return (x, DateTime.ParseExact(results[2], "MMddyyyyhhmmsstt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                             })
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Date == null)
                      .ThenBy(x => x.Date)
                      .ThenBy(x => x.Value)
                      .ToList();
```

**Usage**

```
foreach (var item in orderedList)
   Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
```

**Results**

```
File_1710485_08112019111721AM
File_1242161_08112019010101PM
File_1710480
File_1710488
File_1710489
```

<sub>***Note*** : I have used explicit named tuples for clarity, and you could probably make this look more succinct</sub>

<sub>***Note 2*** : As for being performant, there are other solutions... However unless you are decoding millions of files you will find the call to get the file names outweighs the cost of the routine</sub>